Дом шале, верно ли так писать название ресторана? Не тавтология ли это?
Верно ли в названии, например, ресторана использовать ДОМ ШАЛЕ?
Не тавтология ли это ?


Правильно: дом-шале  (дом в стиле шале)

Здесь дом — существительное, а шале — приложение в постпозиции. Это не тавтология, а определение архитектуры дома. Шале — это небольшой дом сельского типа с покатой крышей из натуральных природных материалов.

Большой толковый словарь русского языка
ШАЛЕ, неизм.; ср. [франц. chalet]. В Швейцарии: небольшой сельский дом в горах. // Небольшой загородный дом; дача такого типа.

Шале́ (фр. chalet от лат. cala «охраняемое место») — тип дома (народная архитектура), характерный для горных районов Альп. Небольшая дача.
Ответ Грамоты №216731
Как правильно: дома-шале или дома шале?
ОТВЕТ. Правильно: дома-шале

Но в текстах встречается вариант дом шале.

Существуют понятия: дом шале, стиль шале, архитектура шале. В этих сочетаниях шале — определяемое существительное с приложениями (дом, стиль, архитектура) в препозиции. Это другое понимание грамматики слова.

О названии ресторана

Название — это имя собственное, там свои правила. За основу берется  нарицательное сочетание: дом шале.
Скорее всего, это будет такой вариант: Дом Шале.
Дом — первое слово имени, а Шале — условное название, в обоих словах прописная буква. Должна быть красивая графика.
